# How to Setup up Gsuite smtp-relay and PHPMailer

Tags: php, smtp, gmail, phpmailer, google-workspace

Hi I've been struggling with how to setup the SMTP-relay that comes with gsuite. I have asked google support but not even they know. What is happening is when i run this code to send emails no emails show up in my gsuite not even in spam either. I have used this exact same code successfully changing the SMTP host to premium64.web-hosting.com and it works great for every email address other than sending to gsuite. I have tried sending it to a different gsuite as well and it still does not work for both the smtp-relay and for the premium64. Thinking it has to be a setting with google admin because google is really strict on security. I have enabled less secure apps. Here below is my code and the current setting. Please show me what needs to be changed so that it works. I've had a tough enough time working on this for the last 4 days. Any help is appreciated and thank you in advance. Thank you.

Phpmailer code:

```
$sentfromemail = "sam@email.com";



$mail = new PHPMailer();

//

$mail->isSMTP();

$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';

$mail->Host = 'smtp-relay.gmail.com';

$mail->Port = '465';

$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Username = $sentfromemail;

$mail->Password = 'correctpassword';

$mail->SetFrom('sam@email.com' , 'Email Name');

$mail->Subject = "test";

$mail-> Body = 'test';
```

Google Admin Console Settings:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you set `$mail->SMTPDebug = 3` and post the SMTP transcript?